# zoom on webpage

Tags: jquery, zooming

i would like to create a zoom effect for my site for visually impaired people.

i currently have the font that adjust based on a user preferences:

i use this script:

http://dev-tips.com/demo/jquery_font_size_change.html

that works great, but the images remains the same size and if the text is too big it mess up the visual aspect of my site.

ideally, a loop will pop and then the user can move over the site and see a zoomed version of it.

is it possible to create a zoom effect using jquery?

Comment: hope http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagemagnify.htm this kind of plug in u required?

Comment: Wouldn't visually impaired users aleady be using their browsers built in zoom features? You can use ctrl+/- or ctrl and mousewheel to size your browser. Why duplicate existing functionality?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the best answer is that every browser currently made supports zoom natively. They will also do a much cleaner job of it than you ever could using javascript. That being said, I think the only way to accomplish this easily would be to code your site using all CSS `%` and `em` values. Then use javascript to increase the width of your main container, thus causing all cascading elements to increase in size. You will also need to edit your default font size and all fonts based on it will increase in size.